# Removing URLs from Nature style references

Tags: cross-referencing, urls, overleaf, mendeley

I have inserted my references into my file using Mendeley reference manager and want to use Nature style referencing. However, I can't seem to remove the URLs which appear in the references. When I use the below code my references appear (with URLs).

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
%\usepackage{bibentry}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage{navigator}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}
```

Adding **\usepackage[style=,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}** below **\bibliographystyle{naturemag}** then removes references completely rather than just the URLs. Any solutions?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also, which one do you need: remove the hyperlinks added to URL text and keep URL text, or remove the URL text.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add an example from my document onto this forum but I am looking to remove the URL text. Right now  can see URLs in each reference where that info is available from Mendeley.